# Implementing Dynamic Type Parsing for Nested Filter Columns in TypeScript with Prisma

Tags: types, nestjs, filtering, prisma

I'm working on a TypeScript project using Prisma for database interaction, and I've created a custom pagination utility that includes a filtering feature. Users of this utility can provide filter conditions including columns, operators, and values. Here's an example of the kind of filter input users might provide:

```
{
  "columns": ["entityA.entityB[].entityC.entityD[].entityE.fieldId"],
  "operators": ["equals"],
  "values": ["12345"]
}
```

In this example, `entityA.entityB[].entityC.entityD[].entityE.fieldId` represents a deeply nested id column in my database models.

The Challenge:
I need to create a parseCondition function that can dynamically parse the values based on the type of the column specified in columns. This is challenging because the column could be deeply nested and I need to correctly infer the type (e.g., integer, string, boolean) of the column from the Prisma model.

Here's the relevant part of my code structure:

```
// repository
    async getEntitiesByParentId(
    parentId: number,
    paginationParams: PaginationParamsDto
  ): Promise<PaginationResultDto<ExampleEntityWithNestedObjects>> {
    const paginateOptions: PaginateOptions<ExampleEntityWithNestedObjects> = {
      orderByFields: [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        // other fields...
      ],
      filterFields: [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3",
        "entityA.entityB[].entityC.entityD[].entityE.fieldId",
        // other fields...
      ],
      where: {
        parentId: parentId,
      },
      include: exampleEntityIncludeOptions,
    };

    const paginate: PaginateFunction<
      ExampleEntityWithNestedObjects,
      typeof this.dbService.exampleEntity
    > = paginator("ExampleEntity");
    return paginate(
      this.dbService.exampleEntity,
      paginationParams,
      paginateOptions
    );
  }
```

```
// types
export type Column<M> = keyof M | RecursiveKeyof<M>;

export type RecursiveKeyof<T> = T extends unknown[]
  ? {
      [K in Extract<keyof T[number], string>]:
        | `${K}`
        | RecursiveKeyofObject<T[number]>;
    }[Extract<keyof T[number], string>]
  : RecursiveKeyofObject<T>;

type RecursiveKeyofObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & (string | number)]: T[K] extends Array<infer R>
    ? R extends object
      ? `${K}[]` | `${K}[]${"."}${RecursiveKeyof<R>}`
      : `${K}[]`
    : T[K] extends object
    ? `${K}` | `${K}.${RecursiveKeyof<T[K]>}`
    : `${K}`;
}[keyof T & (string | number)];

export type IncludeOptions = Record<string, unknown>;
export type WhereOptions = Record<string, unknown>;

export type PaginateOptions<M> = {
  orderByFields?: Column<M>[];
  filterFields?: Column<M>[];
  where?: WhereOptions;
  include?: IncludeOptions;
};

export type PaginateFunction<M, T extends PrismaModel> = (
  model: T,
  paginationParams: PaginationParamsDto,
  paginateOptions: PaginateOptions<M>
) => Promise<PaginationResultDto<M>>;
```

```
export const paginator = <M, T extends PrismaModel>(
  modelName: Prisma.ModelName
): PaginateFunction<M, T> => {
  return async (
    model: T,
    paginationParams: PaginationParamsDto,
    paginateOptions: PaginateOptions<M>
  ) => {
    const { page, perPage, filter, orderBy } = paginationParams;
    const { orderByFields, filterFields, include, where } = paginateOptions;

    // ... implementation ...

    return {
      data,
      meta: {
        total,
        lastPage,
        currentPage: page,
        perPage,
        prev: page > 1 ? page - 1 : null,
        next: page < lastPage ? page + 1 : null,
      },
    };
  };
};
```

How can I implement the parseCondition function to dynamically parse the provided values into their correct types based on the Prisma model's column types, especially for deeply nested columns like in the example above?

Any insights or examples of how to approach this would be very helpful.